# R session uses large amount of memory but no large objects in workspace

Tags: r, memory

after some shortest path operations of the igraph package my Rsession takes up roughly 1.5GB of memory:

```
> gc()
       used    (Mb)   gc trigger   (Mb)  max used  (Mb)
Ncells 13711325 732.3   20885653 1115.5  14807191 790.8
Vcells 52636843 401.6  103420157  789.1 103420157 789.1
```

But I can't find the object that holds all the memory:

```
> print(object.size(x=lapply(ls(all.names = TRUE), get)), units="Mb")
5.6 Mb
```

Restarting the session of course frees up the memory. But I would rather like to not split up my analyses in small batches with session restarts in between.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I'm using the same set operations of the iGraph package a couple of thousend times. After just one operation the R session still just needs roughly 0.15GB, which is the same as after startup. After a couple of thousand operations the R session takes 1.5GB. After the next couple of thousand operations  the R session takes 3GB. I can't find any object that grows in its size. So it's not clear to me, why the RAM usage continuously increases.

When the first iteration can be completed with 0.15GB why should there be the need for the very similar n-th operation to need 3GB? It has the same complexity.

When I watch the system RAM usage I can see that the R session allocates continously more RAM. But I can't find the object that uses that RAM.

Comment: Well, 1.5GB is certainly not that much memory when using R to handle and analyse big(ger) datasets. Also the size of objects does not represent the exact amount of RAM it uses. What kind of operations do you perform? A simple example is `loess()`, which can rack up double digits of GB in RAM when performed on data above 10k rows, but the actuall object that is stored is around 5MB in size.

Comment: I mainly used the shortest path operations of the igraph package. Even if the operation itself migth need RAM in my understanding it should be freed up after termination. The printout above are all done after termination. Maybe I should add that info.

Comment: Perhaps you have some hidden objects which are not picked up with the default `ls()`. Maybe you could experiment with using  `all.names = TRUE` in `ls()`.

Comment: Thx for the hint that objects starting with '.' are not picked by ls(). But unfortunately the size of all objects including those starting with '.' is 5.6MB.

Comment: R doesn't always return all free memory back to the operating system, but it does know when the memory it holds has objects that the user can no longer see, so to speak. If you remove any objects you don't need, you shouldn't have to worry about memory or using `gc`, as soon as new code needs memory, R will check if it can use the memory it already has and re-use it.

Comment: @Alexis: it would be great if R would reuse the RAM when not returned to the OS. But it seems not to reuse it. As mentioned above I'm using the same set operations of the iGraph package a couple of thousend times. After just one operation the R session just needs roughly 0.15GB. After a couple of thousand operations the R session takes 1.5GB. After the next couple of thousand operations  the R session takes 3GB. So when the first iteration can be completed with 0.15GB why should there be the need for the very similar n-th operation to need 3GB?

Comment: That's a bit harder to say without looking at your code and knowing what you save and what you don't, and `igraph` itself could have a memory leak, although I think that's unlikely.